# Event is triggerd twice - by child and parent

Tags: vue.js, events, vuetify.js

I am struggeling to find out why the **updateOptions()** function is triggered twice on the simple example below. I was able to identify (simply by logging) that the @change-event in the **component-to-filter-by-header** is fired first then the @update:options is fired by the parent. To keep the exmaple code below as simple as possible I removed everything else which I think is not the problem

```
 <v-data-table
     @update:options="updateOptions"  // parent event triggered (should not happen)
 >
     <template v-slot:[`header.book`]>
         <component-to-filter-by-header
             @change="updateOptions(...);" // child event triggered
         />
     </template>
     ...
</v-data-table>
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how to prevent the parent component to fire its event

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `@update:options="updateOptions"` is triggered is because options object has headers information as you can see the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props)

And here is how to resolve the problem

You can put .stop modifier in the `ComponentToFilterByHeader` child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click.stop="$emit('change')">click</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope this works!